# Multiple environment deployment

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I know that you can change between different inventory files using the `-i` flag which can be used to switch between different hosts.

In my case, the hosts to be acted upon change between deployments, so I take the hosts in as `--extra-vars` and use `delegate_to` to deploy to that host (see below for more details).

I was hoping for a way to switch between files containing environment variables in a similar fashion. For example, lets say I have the following simplified directory structure:

```
/etc/ansible/
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
└── project/
    └── environments/
        ├── dev/
        │   └── vars.yml
        └── prd/
            └── vars.yml
```

The structure of `vars.yml` in both environments would be exactly the same, just with the variables having different values due to the differences between environments.

I've found a few places that talk about doing something similar such as these:

https://rock-it.pl/managing-multiple-environments-with-ansible-best-practices/

http://rosstuck.com/multistage-environments-with-ansible

http://www.geedew.com/setting-up-ansible-for-multiple-environment-deployments/

In those guides, they act against statically declared hosts. One thing that help me seems to be the directories called `group_vars`. It looks like the inventory points to the config with the same name, and assumingly uses those variables when the `hosts:` directive of a play contains the host(s) specified in the inventory header.

However, Since I dynamically read in the servers that we're acting against via the CLI flag `--extra-vars`, I can't take that approach because I will always have something like this for my plays:

```
...
hosts: localhost
tasks:
    ...
    - name: do something
    ...
    delegate_to: {{ item }}
    with_items: {{ given_hosts }}
```

Or I run a task first that takes the servers and adds them to a new host like this:

```
- name: Extract Hosts
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Adding given hosts to new group...
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: some_group
      with_items:
        - "{{ list_of_hosts | default([]) }}"
```

and then uses the dynamically created group:

```
- name: Restart Tomcat for Changes to Take Effect
  hosts: some_group
  tasks:

    - name: Restarting Tomcat...
      service:
        name: tomcat
        state: restarted
```

So I need to find a way to specify which `vars.yml` to use. Because I use Jenkins to kick off the Ansible playbook via CLI over SSH, I was hoping for something like the following:

`ansible-playbook /path/to/some/playbook.yml --include-vars /etc/ansible/project/dev/vars.yml`

At the least, how would I explicitly include a `vars.yml` file in a playbook to use the variables defined within?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

[extra vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) with `@`: `--extra-vars @/etc/ansible/project/dev/vars.yml`

or

[include_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_vars_module.html):

```
- include_vars: "/etc/ansible/project/{{ some_env }}/vars.yml"
```

to load different variables depending in your environment.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, you always have nice and simple solutions. For the readers: Since I'm already using `--extra-vars` to take input, I just put an `environment` variable in there so when Jenkins calls the `ansible-playbook` command with `--extra-vars`, it injects the user given environment. Then, in my first play, I use `-include_vars` as shown above so I can use the included variables for the rest of the playbook.